# Is there a way to estimate dependence between an observed variable and an unobserved variable?

Tags: time-series, modeling, latent-variable, exploratory-data-analysis, moving-average-model

I'm attempting to do some open-ended exploratory analysis/model building on real-valued time series data.

I am explicitly **not** assuming that all elements of my class of models are linear in the lagged values and/or the lagged errors.

Let $X_t$ denote a time series (in this case, a sequence of real numbers, indexed by discrete time).

Putting aside the discussion of the impact of stationarity/nonstationarity, for purely autoregressive models, learning about the dependence structure between say $X_{t-1}$ and $X_t$ seems relatively approachable in that one can estimate various statistics between them such as correlation or mutual information to quantify the amount of dependence between them and among other methods, can plot one against the other to determine potentially how they depend on each other.

Let us assume that for whatever reason, perhaps through use of Auto Mutual Information/Partial Auto Mutual Information and extending the usual heuristics of ACF/PACF plots to the AMI/PAMI plots, we decide that a good model might be a not-necessarily-linear MA(1) model:

$$X_t = m(\varepsilon_{t-1}) + \varepsilon_t, m \in \mathcal{M}.$$

where $\mathcal{M}$ is our collection of models under consideration such as linear regressions or neural networks.

What I'm wanting to know is, is there a way we can do a similar sort of thing for $\varepsilon_{t-1}$ and $X_t$ as previously described for $X_{t-1}$ and $X_t$ (visualizing/estimating dependence without assuming a relation) despite $\varepsilon_{t-1}$ being unobservable? Moreso, can we do it without assuming a functional form for $m$ and approximating the errors as detailed [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/505873/how-to-manually-fit-ma1-model-with-ols)? (very good intuition for MA models in that post, btw)

I realize that this may probably not be feasible/really possible due to the relaxing of tractability assumptions and completely get if assuming a functional form for $m$ while recursively approximating the error terms and estimating the parameters of $m$ is the "best" we can do due to the latent nature of the true error terms.

I know that [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16673/fitting-data-based-on-an-unobserved-variable) post somewhat addresses my question, but am unsure how to apply what's there to my exploratory data analysis that I want to apply to the error terms.

Thanks as always! :)

Comment: Is your question about gaining insight into a vector of errors under differing assumptions and specifications? Or is about fitting a Box-Jenkins time series model? If the latter then further exploration of latent structures doesn't fall under that rubric. Partial least squares is one approach to supervised modeling of latent structures. Another supervised approach is latent class analysis which partitions the heterogeneity in a vector of errors into homogenous clusters. LCA is kind of old school, 20th c stuff today. More recent is the work of David Dunson at Duke, browse his papers on tensors

Comment: @MikeHunter thank you for the clarifying question, I may have to look into those references. Also, I think that my question falls more into the former? I am wanting to know if there's a way to quantify, or at least try to quantify (such as with plotting observations of a variable against observations of another variable in the case of two observed variables) the type/magnitude of dependence between an unobserved/latent variable (realizations of $\varepsilon_{t-1}$) and an observed variable (realizations of $X_t), ideally without first having to assume some model (e.g. a linear MA(1) model).

Comment: Well, why not subtract lagged variates of $X_t from $X_t and analyze the residuals? Simple, no assumed model. Latent class models are doing only slightly more in partitioning the heterogeneity in the single vector of errors from a supervised model.

Comment: @MikeHunter Wouldn't this indirectly assume that our model is of the form $X_t = X_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t$?

Comment: *Indirectly* being the operative word. If you can think of something with absolutely no assumptions of any kind, I'd be interested in hearing about it.